# apple push notification using moonApns

Tags: ios, asp.net, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, moonapns

i am trying to send push notifications to apple using `moon apns` 
but getting the following errors

```
{"An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate"}
{"A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception."}
```

this is the error line

```
 _apnsStream.BeginRead(response, 0, 6, ReadResponse, new MyAsyncInfo(response, _apnsStream));
```

i looked for the solutions but nothing worked out?
can anybody tell me why am i getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

attempt to replace this line:

```
_apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
```

To

```
_apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);
```